# eclipse java servlet no me redicciona a la pagina

Tags: java, sql

soy novato en el mundo de la programacion actualmente estoy haciendo un login usando jsp con conexion a sql server pero cuando ingreso me sale lo siguiente

[image: me arroja el siguiente error]

el codigo del conexion java

```
public class Conexion 
{
  String url;
  String user;
  String pass;
  String driver;
  //constructor
  
  public Conexion() 
  {
      this.url="dbc:sqlserver://misc.database.windows.net";
      this.user="admin";
      this.pass="admin";
      this.driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
  }
 public String getUrl() 
 {
     return url;
 }
 
 public String getUser() {
     return user;
 }
 
 public String getPass() {
     return pass;
 }
 
 public String getDriver()
 {
     return driver;
 }
}
```

codigo de validación usuario

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class UsersDao 
{
     Conexion db = new Conexion();
     String sql="";
     Connection con;
     PreparedStatement pst;
     ResultSet rs;
     
     public UsersDao() {}
     
     public int validar(String Usuario, String Pass) throws ClassNotFoundException
     {
         int nivel =0;
         try 
         {
             Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
             con=DriverManager.getConnection(db.getUrl(),db.getUser(),db.getPass());
             sql="SELECT perfil from users WHERE email='"+Usuario+"'AND password='"+Pass+"'";
             pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
             rs=pst.executeQuery();
             while(rs.next()) 
             {
                 nivel=rs.getInt(1);
             }
             con.close();
             rs.close();
             return nivel;
             
         }catch(Exception e) 
         {
             return nivel;
         }
         
     }
}
```

codigo usado en el servlet Login pero en web.xml eclipse no me lo esta tomando

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import loginpackage.UsersDao;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Login
 */
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Login() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        String nombre;
        String clave;
        int nivel=0;
        UsersDao dao = new UsersDao ();
        RequestDispatcher rd=null;
        if(request.getParameter("ingresar")!=null) 
        {
           nombre=request.getParameter("email");
           clave=request.getParameter("password");
           try {
            nivel = dao.validar(nombre, clave);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           request.setAttribute("nivel", nivel);
           request.setAttribute("nombre", nombre);
           rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        }
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
        String nombre;
        String clave;
        int nivel=0;
        UsersDao dao = new UsersDao ();
        RequestDispatcher rd=null;
        if(request.getParameter("ingresar")!=null) 
        {
           nombre=request.getParameter("email");
           clave=request.getParameter("password");
           try {
            nivel = dao.validar(nombre, clave);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           request.setAttribute("nivel", nivel);
           request.setAttribute("nombre", nombre);
           rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        }
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
```

error mostrado:
[image: este es el error mostrado]

les agradezco su colaboración ya que a traves de ella aprendo

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que no tienes problemas de conexión ni de base de datos.

Al crear el Servlet puedes indicar que este se agregue al web.xml. Si no, tienes que agregar el path.

Además si la pétición viene por POST la estas enviando al doGet();. Pero tambien tienes el mismo código en ambos métodos. Te dejo un ejemplo de como podría funcionar. Saludos

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name = "Login", urlPatterns = {"/Login"})
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
        response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    
        String nombre;
        String clave;
        int nivel = 0;
        UsersDao dao = new UsersDao();
    
        if (request.getParameter("ingresar") != null) {
            nombre = request.getParameter("email");
            clave = request.getParameter("password");
            try {
                nivel = dao.validar(nombre, clave);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            request.setAttribute("nivel", nivel);
            request.setAttribute("nombre", nombre);
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
             throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```